# Enable scanning in a browser using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am developing a system using laravel 5.4 that can be used to scan a document and send it to the database. I have tried to run

"composer require scannerjs/scanner.js"

and got stuck right there. How can i successfully implement the above? Thanks

Comment: What the problem?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto iam failing to create an interface to scan a document in a laravel system

Comment: Can you share the exact error that you are getting? Also, have you tried Bower?